# Windows tells me there isn't enough memory and asks to close Firefox, but why this actually happens is unclear

Tags: windows-7, virtual-memory, memory-leaks

My system has 4GB of physical memory, and a system managed paging file on an SSD. It seems like the paging file's size is capped to 12GB for a total of 16GB memory, which should be more than enough, and hasn't caused me any problems until very recently.

Here are the error details taken from the event viewer: http://pastebin.com/iACX7EES

To me it looks like my programs aren't actually the ones using up memory, but somehow the cap gets reached anyway and I'm forced to close Firefox. This usually happens after Firefox has been on for a long time. If I refuse to close Firefox myself, Windows closes it automatically in only a few seconds.

What's going on, and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: watch: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405 .. after that, play around with vmmap and rammap (both tools of the sysinternal suite).

Comment: Double check all your add-ons (type about:addons in the url bar) and be sure there is nothing installed there that you don't know. Firefox itself probably doens't have a memory leak, because mozilla works very hard to avoid them, but any 3rd party plug in might.

Comment: The video certainly cleared up a lot of things, but it also left me unsure of whether I understood some things correctly, so correct me if I'm wrong. If you add together the free memory and the amount currently in use as shown by VMMap, you'd get the maximum amount that process can end up using. Both flash player and Firefox could use 4GB if it's correct. That's a bunch of memory, but not enough to explain all 16GB getting filled up. Do I just need to wait for the error to appear again and then look into it with these tools, or is there a simple explanation for what's causing the problem?